# How can I merge 2 google analytics tags from the same URL

Tags: google-analytics

I have a unique website, that for some reason, 2 analytics tags were created for.

So the first tags was created for the first 3 months of the websites life, and the other was created the 4th month.

Now I want to merge the two tags somehow so that I don't lose the analytics of the first 3 months.

The reason that the second tag was created is that I thought I lost the account that it was linked but this is not true.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging Properties in Google Analytics is not possible, so you cannot transfer data from the first to the second Property (or vice versa).

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, Google analytics track your verified url, if your url is already verified then second account does not approved the another tag. Please see your code correct is working or not